# how to make 2 stage for loop statement from 1 stage for loop in c?

Tags: c

I'd like to make 2 stage for loop statment from 1 stage in the c.

```
     //gray rgb
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x * y; i++) 
    { 
    *(buff2 + i * 3 + 0) = data_[i];
    *(buff2 + i * 3 + 1) = data_[i];
    *(buff2 + i * 3 + 2) = data_[i];
    }
```

But actually I can't get think how do I can make 2 stage.
Can you give a any hint?

Comment: will you explain what those 2 loops will do to give you the right hint

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "2-stage". Could you elaborate?

Comment: By two-stage, do you mean two nested loops, such as `for(i = ...; ... ; ...) for(j = ...; ...; ...)`? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: You will have to edit your question to better explain what you are talking about. two-stage / 1 stage have no meaning in c++. Perhaps you are talking about nested loops but its not clear what you want to nest. You need to post more context.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hope it would help you:-

```
for(i=0;i<x;i++)
{
        for(j=0;j<y;j++)
        {
                *(buff2 + i*y + j) = data_[i*y+j]
        }
}
```

Comment: That does something quite different!

Comment: @MartinBonner, i believe to represent  image OP has 1-D array of type ‘unsigned byte’ having size x*y. It then puts values from 0 through x*y in each row. that's why he asked how to represent in two stage if size is x*y.

Comment: @MartinBonner i don't think so, i'm in wrong here. Although OP has attempted to solve that issue but it was not correct, just look at his logic.

Comment: He has array which is x.y.3 - the last axis is for rgb

Comment: @MartinBonner  In this answer,  I can't write the data which I want to write 3 times at once.

Comment: Who accept this answer, please remove this down vote also.